# 4th member of each row comes out of alignment in a grid in css

Tags: html, css

I have **16 boxes**, in which i have **4 boxes** grouped together.

in `my code 4th member of each row get out of alignment comes down to next line`.

**i want to make the 4 group appear in a single row..without the last element without droping down**

How to correct this and make 4 group to stay in a single line.

How to correct this and make 4 group to stay in a single line.

**How to correct this and make 4 group to stay in a single line.**

```css
.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 9px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:2px solid white;
  
  
  margin: -2px;
  background-color: #666666;

  height: 10vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#container {
    white-space:nowrap;
 border:px solid #CC0000;
 
}

.containerr{
 border:px solid #FF3399;
 } 
.pic{
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 } 
 
.container2 {
  width: 29.0vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0.9vh;
  left: 19.2vw;
}
.box p {
 font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}
p{
font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
font-size:15px;

 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                 0px -5px 35px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);

color: #005ce6;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
      <div class="containerr">
        <div class="pic" id="content">


           <div id="container">
            
                <div class="box"  id="1"><p name="values">1</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="2"><p name="values">2</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="3"><p name="values">3</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="4"><p name="values">4</p></div>
            </div>
             <div id="2container">
            
                <div class="box"  id="5"><p name="values">5</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="6"><p name="values">6</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="7"><p name="values">7</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="8"><p name="values">8</p></div>
            </div>
            <div id="3container">
            
                <div class="box"  id="9"><p name="values">9</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="10"><p name="values">10</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="11"><p name="values">11</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="12"><p name="values">12</p></div>
            </div>
            <div id="4container">
            
                <div class="box"  id="13"><p name="values">13</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="14"><p name="values">14</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="15"><p name="values">15</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="16"><p name="values">16</p></div>
            </div>
             
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That’s not due to them being the fourth items, but that the paragraphs inside them contain a character, whereas in the others they are all empty - which makes them render with different height.

Comment: Yes, they're trying to align themselves to the baseline, but the empty ones don't have a baseline. And I presume that the unwanted wrapping is caused by the fact that you're trying to cram 4 boxes with width 33% in the container. That doesn't fit!

Comment: @misorude now check the code

Comment: @mr-lister  now check the code

Comment: @Jupiter OK, so you have solved the problem of the empty boxes, but not the width yet. You meant `calc(25% - 9px)`. Also, I see the declaration for `font` in the `p` is not OK, causing it to be ignored.

Comment: @mr-lister calc(25% - 9px)  worked

Comment: @mr-lister   can you explain what you say about `p` a little bit more

Comment: `font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;` - that is not a valid value for the `font`shorthand property; see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font#Syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using display:flex;

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
   white-space:nowrap;
 border:1px solid #CC0000;
}

.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 9px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:2px solid white;
  
  
  margin: -2px;
  background-color: #666666;

  height: auto;
  
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.pic{
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 } 
 
.container2 {
  width: 29.0vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0.9vh;
  left: 19.2vw;
}
.box p {
 font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}
p{
font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
font-size:15px;

 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),
                 0px -5px 35px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);

color: #005ce6;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
      <div class="containerr">
        <div class="pic" id="content">


           <div class="container">
            
                <div class="box"  id="1"><p name="values">1</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="2"><p name="values">2</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="3"><p name="values">3</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="4"><p name="values">4</p></div>
            </div>
             <div class="container">
            
                <div class="box"  id="5"><p name="values">5</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="6"><p name="values">6</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="7"><p name="values">7</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="8"><p name="values">8</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
            
                <div class="box"  id="9"><p name="values">9</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="10"><p name="values">10</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="11"><p name="values">11</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="12"><p name="values">12</p></div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
            
                <div class="box"  id="13"><p name="values">13</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="14"><p name="values">14</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="15"><p name="values">15</p></div>
                <div class="box"  id="16"><p name="values">16</p></div>
            </div>
             
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```